# ¿Como pasar la referencia de una variable (io -> Socket.io) a una clase en JS [Node.js]?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket.io, es6

Quisiera saber cual es la forma correcta de pasarle la referencia de la variable io a una clase en Node.js

Actualmente tengo inicializada la variable en un archivo `index.js` :

```
const io = require('socket.io').listen(9000)
```

Leyendo algunos blogs he observado que solo le pasan la variable al constructor de esta forma:

```
class Foo{
    constructor(io){
        this.io = io
    }
}

let objFoo = new Foo(io)
```

Sin embargo, io contiene en su interior un objeto con los sockets activos,  la pregunta es: ¿El atributo `io` de la clase contendrá las conexiones (sockets activos) que se hagan posterior a la instanciación de la misma? de no ser asi ¿Existe alguna otra forma de hacer referencia a la variable io desde otro documento .js (pues la clase se encuentra en otro doc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `¿El atributo io de la clase contendrá las conexiones (sockets activos) que se hagan posterior a la instanciación de la misma?`

Recuerda que, en Javascript, los **Objetos** (datos no *primitivos*) se pasan **por referencia**.

Eso quiere decir que, en realidad, estas usando **exactamente el mismo objeto** en todas partes. Aunque lo copies (como indicas en tu ejemplo), en realidad seguirás usando **el mismo objeto**, si bien con varios nombres distintos.

En resumen: **si**, contendrá cualquier cosa que contenga el objeto original, puesto que es el mismo. Aunque se añada **después** de copiarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer un archivo donde levantas el socket con io y exportas esa variable:

Sería algo como esto: **socket.js**

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

module.exports = io
```

Y en donde quieras usarlo sería algo como: **archivo.js**

```
const io = require('./rutaArchivo/socket')
```